# 22.04 Says I'm not connected to the internet but I am

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I just setup a new machine with Ubuntu 22.04 Server.  I am connected to the internet as I can browse and download files with no issues.  When I go to settings to add an online account, it tells me that I am not connected to the internet.  The network settings only show VPN settings and not Ethernet (currenly plugged in).  The network dropdown on the top bar says Unmanaged and the options are Connect and Wired Settings.  Neither one shows on the Network Settings menu.

I can't find any good help to fix the issue.    Any thoughts?

"lshw -c net" output

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:25:00:ef:d7:bf
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic firmware=1.9-0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:8b400000-8b41ffff memory:8b420000-8b42ffff ioport:2000(size=32) memory:8b430000-8b433fff memory:8b440000-8b47ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: enp10s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:25:00:ef:ff:c8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic duplex=full firmware=1.9-0 ip=192.168.86.24 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:8b300000-8b31ffff memory:8b320000-8b32ffff ioport:1000(size=32) memory:8b330000-8b333fff memory:8b340000-8b37ffff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:8b100000-8b103fff
```

"netplan yaml" output (I know both ports are the same ip.  They will never be used together.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp9s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.86.24/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.86.1
    enp10s0:  
      addresses:
        - 192.168.86.24/24
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.86.1
```

"NetworkManager.conf" output

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit to add…
I have a gui installed for easier management for me.

Comment: If it is a server, how are you "going to settings"? Did you install a graphical desktop? Servers typically don't have `network-manager` installed which the graphical desktops typically use.

Comment: Yes.  I installed a desktop.  I like all the command line stuff but I still feel more comfortable with a gui interface on things I don't know how to do via command line.

Comment: That kind of crucial information should go in your question.

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: No vpn.   But strangely enough, that is the only option on the networking tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish for your networking to be controlled by the graphical interface; that is, Network Manager, please amend your netplan yaml file. First, back up the current file:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/*.yaml  /etc/netplan/*.bak
```

Write a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Write the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc., so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to have fixed it.  I have the network controls showing up now.